# Are limits preserved if we change the variable to something that grows similarly?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Say I want the limit of $f(g(x))$.

Is this limit going to be the same as finding the limit of $f(h(x))$ where $h$ grows similarly like $g$, meaning $\lim \frac{g(x)}{h(x)} = 1$?

Comment: Not without some continuity assumption on $f$.

Comment: Are you assuming that $h(x),g(x)\to\infty$? If not, what use the word 'grow'?